# Catel: Fire Events after InitializeAsync in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

At startup of my application I test some connections to other systems. I fire events to get viewmodels informed of the state of this connections.

I use a Catel `TabControl` to show my views. I set `LoadTabItems` to `"EagerLoading"` and subscribe to the events in the method `InitializeAsync` in my ViewModels.

The problem is the events are fired before all viewmodels are created. How to get informed when all viewmodels are initialized to check the connections and fire the events.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a service or manager called *ConnectionManager*. This will check for the events (since this is a long living object, probably registered in the IoC container). Then in your vm, it doesn't matter if the events are already fired or not, the *ConnectionManager* will give you the answer.

Remember that view models are short living objects (they are gone as soon as your views are gone). If you want to maintain state, use managers / services.